# Rendering artifacts on Bootstrap modals in IE11 and Edge

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, artifact

I am repeatedly experiencing Rendering artifacts on several versions of IE11 and Edge, as well as several different devices with different graphics cards and drivers, and different update states of Windows 10.

The blue arrows on the screenshots point to some of them. On this screenshot, the artifacts result form closing dropdown lists. But they may also appear around charts.

Interesting point: They only occur on Bootstrap modals.

How can I avoid them?

The artifacts are parts of the underlying page content. It seems as if changes on the modal `<div>` (for instance erased dropdown lists) lead to parts of the main page becoming rendered over the modal.

[image]

Code snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#mymodal').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="form-control" id="birthdayYear" name="birthdayYear"
            required="">
            <option></option>
           
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" id="birthdayMonth" name="birthdayMonth"
            required="">
            <option></option>
         
            <option value="1">Januar</option>
            <option value="2">Februar</option>
            <option value="3">März</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">Mai</option>
            <option value="6">Juni</option>
            <option value="7">Juli</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">Oktober</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">Dezember</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" id="birthdayYear" name="birthdayYear"
            required="">
            <option></option>
          
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="1974">1974</option>
            <option value="1973">1973</option>
            <option value="1972">1972</option>
            <option value="1971">1971</option>
            <option value="1970">1970</option>
            <option value="1969">1969</option>
            <option value="1968">1968</option>
            <option value="1967">1967</option>
            <option value="1966">1966</option>
            <option value="1965">1965</option>
            <option value="1964">1964</option>
            <option value="1963">1963</option>
            <option value="1962">1962</option>
            <option value="1961">1961</option>
            <option value="1960">1960</option>
            <option value="1959">1959</option>
            <option value="1958">1958</option>
            <option value="1957">1957</option>
            <option value="1956">1956</option>
            <option value="1955">1955</option>
            <option value="1954">1954</option>
            <option value="1953">1953</option>
            <option value="1952">1952</option>
            <option value="1951">1951</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="1949">1949</option>
            <option value="1948">1948</option>
            <option value="1947">1947</option>
            <option value="1946">1946</option>
            <option value="1945">1945</option>
            <option value="1944">1944</option>
            <option value="1943">1943</option>
            <option value="1942">1942</option>
            <option value="1941">1941</option>
            <option value="1940">1940</option>
            <option value="1939">1939</option>
            <option value="1938">1938</option>
            <option value="1937">1937</option>
            <option value="1936">1936</option>
            <option value="1935">1935</option>
            <option value="1934">1934</option>
            <option value="1933">1933</option>
            <option value="1932">1932</option>
            <option value="1931">1931</option>
            <option value="1930">1930</option>
            <option value="1929">1929</option>
            <option value="1928">1928</option>
            <option value="1927">1927</option>
            <option value="1926">1926</option>
            <option value="1925">1925</option>
            <option value="1924">1924</option>
            <option value="1923">1923</option>
            <option value="1922">1922</option>
            <option value="1921">1921</option>
            <option value="1920">1920</option>
            <option value="1919">1919</option>
            <option value="1918">1918</option>
            <option value="1917">1917</option>
            <option value="1916">1916</option>
            <option value="1915">1915</option>
            <option value="1914">1914</option>
            <option value="1913">1913</option>
            <option value="1912">1912</option>
            <option value="1911">1911</option>
            <option value="1910">1910</option>
            <option value="1909">1909</option>
            <option value="1908">1908</option>
            <option value="1907">1907</option>
            <option value="1906">1906</option>
            <option value="1905">1905</option>
            <option value="1904">1904</option>
            <option value="1903">1903</option>
            <option value="1902">1902</option>
            <option value="1901">1901</option>
            <option value="1900">1900</option>
            <option value="1899">1899</option>
            <option value="1898">1898</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result in IE11 and Edge:

[image]

Comment: @ideaboxer When you re-visit this site and don't know why the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824413/3785314) has been deleted and why there is a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127530/3785314) with many up-votes, that's because you've been duped into accepting answer from the wrong user but SO users came together and fixed it. Please, read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370366/what-to-do-when-someone-is-posting-under-your-username). You can now accept the [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127530/3785314).

Answer (score 58):

You can trigger a different rendering by using CSS:

```
transform: scale(1);
```

---

In your case, you said that does not prevent the artifacts, but making it *slightly* lower/higher does:

```
transform: scale(0.99999);
```

or:

```
transform: scale(1.00001);
```

---

An alternative way of altering the rendering would be:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

*Note: This may change the text-aliasing a little.*